# VirtualBox - Two guests can't ping each other

Tags: networking, windows-xp, virtualbox

I've selected bridged adapter option in virtualbox. I am able to ping from Machine 1 (WinXP) to Machine 2(Linux) and get a response, but I am not able to ping vice versa. I need to connect from Machine 2 to Machine 1. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable ICMP echo requests on the Windows machine by doing the following: https://readme.phys.ethz.ch/windows/how_to_enable_icmp_echo_requests_ping_in_windows_xp_service_pack_2/

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)